# Log the files in database when using resumable.js

Tags: javascript, python, flask

How can I log the file attributes such as file name, file size, modification time in any database table at the time of file uploading also I need to keep track in database table which files have been cancelled and paused while uploading using Resumable.js. How can I implement this at server side. I am using python flask on server side.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please show us in a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) what you've tried.  Also, please read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Avoid asking multiple questions in a single post.

Comment: Ok.I want to log the cancel and pause events of resumable.js in database.How can i do it?